# How to repair the already installed umbraco?

Tags: umbraco

I have installed Umbraco 4.0 after implementing some feature, i am getting some error,

Do we have any provision to repair  Umbraco installation ? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

This is very vague, could you maybe give us some more detail on the error you are receiving?
Also, did you install umbraco, then add a new feature and it broke ?

As a general rule of thumb when working with cms content, it is best to make a backup of both your database and file system when performing maintenance on cms installations to avoid possible data or content loss.

Umbraco by itself does not have a built in "repair" feature, however you could overwrite the files on disk with a fresh copy of umbraco 4, provided it is the same version. You will have to rebuild your site index when done.

Note: I say overwrite because you simply want to replace all the umbraco files on disk and preserve your old content files such as media etc, however if you have made any changes to the umbraco core, those changes will be lost by doing the overwrite.